# Asset Browser Will Not Update As Expected

Tags: cache, asset-browser, asset, library

my asset library consists of a number of well organised blend files used exclusively for storing my assets for use in the Asset Browser. Within my asset browser I use a set of classification tress to make using assets easier.

For exmaple:

> Materials & Textures
>
> > Concrete
> > Wood
> > Metals

> Objects[Scifi]
>
> > Architecture
> > Items
> > Clutter

> Nature
>
> > Trees
> > Grass
> > Rocks

You get the point.

My issue is that sometimes I decide to update these trees to better categorise or simplify the organisation, but when I open a blend file housing the assets/categories to be updated, once I am done and saved. The Asset categories from that file are just broken, often deleted and all the assets in that file end up in 'Unassigned'. Other times the categories remain but the assets are still in the 'unassigned' section. Even after refreshing the library and trying other things. I can reopen the blend file storing the assets and under the 'current project' designation everything looks fine in there. The assets are in their categories etc. It just doesn't update in the Asset Library proper.

I've tried so many things, and I have got the library to update before but it's so random I cannot tell you what makes it work, which is the most frustrating part as this can eat hours of my time.

Things I've done:

1. Deleting the file path in preferences, closing Blender, reopening Blender and readding the file path. (Don't think this has ever worked on its own.)
2. On the drop moving from 'All' to selecting the broken asset library blend file, hoping it will force the cache to update. (Pretty certain this has helped before.)
3. Copying a backup of the file elsewhere, deleting the original and all it's files, opening the back up and resaving back to it's original location. (Maybe this has helped, I'm not sure.)

Typically, as I am now and what prompted me to finally seek help with this, I have to do all of these 'fixes', sometimes multiple times, along which I have to retype all of my categories in the asset library blend file and place the assets in them again multiple times, which is beyond tedious. Of which, there is no guarantee it will work. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

On the one I was just updating today, I only wanted to create a new sub-category and move one asset within the file to it and it broke the entire library leading to an hour of trying to fix it. Now all those assets are in the 'Unassigned' category. It's crazy.

Please, I really hope someone has some helpful insight in to this as it is driving me nuts.

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to add that I am on a powerful computer. All the files are stored on m.2 NVMe drives, and I am using Blender 3.5.

Comment: Make sure in your entire library there is only one file named blender-assets.cat.txt at the root of the library, if there is one in the child folder where your asset blend file is located it will overwrite the catalog definitions and unsync everything

Comment: Each blend file that is used for storing assets are stored within their own folders.

For example:
Blender Resources\Asset Projects\Natures Assets\Nature Asset.blend
Blender Resources\Asset Projects\Scifi Assets\Scifi Assets.blend

One Blend file per folder. Inside every folder is a 'blender_assets.cats.txt' and a 'blender_assets.cats.txt~'. The categories update okay most of the time. The issue, like now is that the categories appear but the assets are not put into the categories and are left in unassigned. 

Where does blender save the info for which category an asset belongs to?

Comment: Like I said if you have an asset library, the information is stored in a single blender_assets.cats.txt file, at the root of the library. You can check out the insides if you open it with a text editor, it's a text file. You should *not* have a blender_assets.cats.txt file for every blend file in your library.

Comment: I do have one for every blend because the blends are in different folders. Are you saying that all asset blends must be kept in a single folder?

I have looked in the .txt files before, and they only store the categories. They don't tell assets which category they're supposed to be in which is the main issue.

Comment: Each asset blend file can be in subfolders, but there should only be one blender-assets.cats.txt  at the root of the library. The information that tells Blender which catalog an asset belongs to is the catalog guid which is linked to the individual asset, the string of letters and digits that's written in the txt file. You can see it if you enable developer tools and asset debug info in the experimental preferences. If you modify your catalogs in one txt file and not in the others, the guid will not update accordingly leading to a discrepancy

Comment: Okay thanks, I still haven't been able to solve the problem but this did reveal some more insight in to the problem.
---
To simplify I opened one of my Asset Blends and saved it to a brand new location. Re-made the categories and put the assets in them. There is only one txt file in the directory.
---
After enabling the asset debug I can see that inside the Asset Blend, where everything looks fine, the assets have the correct category string, but looking at the assets in a new Blend the assets are in 'unassigned' with an incorrect string. Clearing and re-marking an asset didn't help.